# Pulling Current From a Cell Phone Port

Tags: current, current-sink

I have a Samsung Galaxy S9 that I am trying to pull current from via power resistors. I have been able to pull 0.927 Amps from the USB-C port but every time I get above that, the phone stops outputting. I have been told that there are some tricks that allow you to pull 1.5 Amps and higher, but have not been able to get higher than 0.927 A. Does anyone know any of those tricks or have any ideas?

The port outputs 5.298 V. The resistor that I am using is a little over 4.8 Ohms and the current output is 0.927 A. I know this does not look right but when I connect the resistors, the voltage drops down to around 4.5 V. Lowering the resistance does not help. I have lowered it 0.03 ohms and the output has turned off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNxEpY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? The port is likely controlled by a DC to DC converter with a current limit, you wont get more current out of it.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your "unloaded" schematic shows a short-circuit across the voltage source. This would generally fall into the "not a good idea" category.

Comment: I am doing this to see how long I can run its battery at 1.5 Amps or higher. In case I would like to power a device that needs that kind of power

Comment: A phone is an absurdly expensive way to get a weak powerbank.

Answer (score 2):

If you use your phone as power provider, it is a function/property of that source how much current it can supply. It does what it is designed to do. A small battery-powered (like a smartphone) device is not supposed to serve as a "power bank", and apparently limits itself. A phone with Type-C connector, when it enters "provider mode", must "advertise" its current source capability by means of pull-up resistor to +5V (or corresponding pull-up current) on CC (communication channel) pins.

Again, it is a property of phone. If it has 56k pull-up, it is designed to supply the standard legacy load (500-900 mA) only. If the pull-up is 22k, it can supply 1.5 A, and if 10k - up to 3 A. Now it is a function of attached power consumer (load) to determine this capability (by measuring these pull-ups) and configure itself to take no more current than advertised by provider. There is no "tricks" on device side other than a 5.1k pull-down resistor. The provider doesn't measure anything, it only "advertises" its capability, so there could be no "tricks".

Apparently you have experimentally determined that your phone has a built-in limit for a basic legacy load, no more.

There could be "tricks" to fool a device into thinking that it can take more current by tricking/changing the advertised pull-up values on the host side, but if the host has the built-in limit, no tricks can force it to change the limit.

Comment: What I am asking is to test the capabilities of the phone, not the battery. My actual task was to try and pull 1.5 Amps from the battery and if I completed that, to pull 5 Amps from the battery, but it seems with what I have, it cannot be done. Thanks for the information in this answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @jack27871, well, it seems that you successfully accomplished the task of determining the phone designed limit, 0.927 A. It is actually a requirement for a charging port to "softly" drop supplied voltage when  the load approaches maximum value. It is done so the consuming device can monitor the drop and limit its consumption without being completely disconnected. This functionality of your phone has little-to-nothing to do with parametrics of employed battery, the phone will continue to behave that way regardless of battery capacity or else (if it is charged).

Comment: I know it has been awhile, but I forgot to ask you if there was a document where I could find this information in your answer. Is there one and if so, could you point me to it? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The phone likely has somewhere around a 2200mAH battery - my Samsung S3 did anyway.  2200mAH/1500mA = 1.45 Hr max. At high a draw, things would likely overheat and shut down sooner tho.

This [Samsung Spec page](https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/galaxy-s9/specs/) shows 3000mAH. So two hours tops.

Comment: The S9 has a 3000 mAh battery and I know that it should theoretically last 2 hours. But those things that you mention at the end are what I would like to know. When would it overheat and shut down is the main question. But as in the answer below, it is likely that I cannot draw any more current.

Comment: Without schematics and knowledge of parts used, I cannot offer more.

Comment: This is irrelevant.  The issue is not the cell *capacity* and the cell itself can likely support the draw rate, rather the issue is the charge pump and related circuitry between the cell and the USB port are *not intended* to support high current external loads.  The idea here is you could maybe power a flash drive or some low current accessory.

Comment: @jack27871, under standard discharge conditions (at 1-2 A) the battery itself will never overheat. The internal source of battery heating is its serial resistance, which is about 0.1 Ohms. At 2 A this will result in power dissipation of below 400 mW, which is nearly nothing for the battery of such physical size. The phone, however, may get pretty worm under heavy use, since its electronics will dissipate about 8-10 W, which is something.